# Area Between Inscribed Circles and Rectangle

Tags: geometry

I was reviewing past exam questions for a math competition known as UIL Calculator Applications when I stumbled across the following question:

**A large amount of dough is rolled out and as many circular cookies as possible are cut from the rolled-out dough. The remaining dough is piled together, rerolled and more circular cookies are similarly cut. What percent of the original amount of dough is left over?**

Here's my incorrect attempt, if you'd like:

First, I imagined that I was cutting one circle out of a square with side length $x$, with 4 points tangent to the circle. Therefore, the remaining area would be $$x^2-\pi(\frac{x}2)^2$$

Then, I imagined that I was cutting nine circles out of a square with side length $x$, with each circle tangent to the square and/or to adjacent circles. Therefore, the remaining area would be $$x^2-9\pi(\frac{x}6)^2$$ which is the same result as the first scenario. 
So the percent of original amount of dough left over after 1 "cut" for any number of circles is $$\frac{x^2(1-\frac{\pi}4)}{x^2}\approx21.46\%$$ and after 2 "cuts" the percent of original amount of dough left over is $$(21.46\%)^2\approx4.61\%$$

According to the answer key, however, the answer rounded to 3 significant digits is $.867\%$ and I'm not sure as to how.

Answer (score 1):

A grid of hexagons is more efficient than a grid of squares, using $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$ of the dough instead of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.